# if statement erroron button click

Tags: java, android

can someone please help making pairs game and using this if statement can someone tell me if theres a bracket or semi colon missing cant see whats missing (pic2.getTag() == beck) is underlined have 4 buttons want to pair or reset them the buttons start with set tag name (boots) this works but no good for non match
This works

```
     if (pic2.getTag() == pic1.getTag()){            
    pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
```

THis doesnt

```
 pic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {  
      public void onClick(View v) {  
         pic1.setTag(beck); 
         pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.becks);                           
         if (pic2.getTag() == beck) {
            pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }
      }
 });
```

Comment: What class those variables?  Also; do you get any compile errors?

Comment: Have you tried to put "" in beck?

Comment: " "   these are what were missing well spotted i  randomly tried that and it done the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the compare operator `==`. `View tags` are `Objects` (most probably `Strings`), so you need to compare them with `equals`.-

```
if (pic2.getTag().equals(pic1.getTag()))
```

and

```
if (pic2.getTag().equals(beck))
```